# ¿Es esta frase correcta en español o es una mala traducción de una computadora? "Un ideal no tiene por qué ser siempre principal"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, ortografía

De Wikipedia sobre [ideales principales](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_principal):

> Consideremos el anillo (matemáticas) *R*. Entonces el conjunto de todos
> los múltiplos de 3 es el ideal principal generado por 3, puesto que un
> entero n es múltiplo de 3 precisamente cuando existe un número entero
> k tal que n=3k.
>
> Un ideal **no tiene por qué ser** siempre principal.

Debe ser "**no tiene que ser**", ¿verdad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP no pregunta sobre la diferencia entre "por qué", "porque", "porqué" y "por que", sino que no entiende **la diferencia entre: *no tiene por qué ser* y *no tiene que ser***.

Existe una diferencia fundamental de sentido: mientras que "no tiene por qué ser siempre principal" indica que no hay motivo o razón para que sea siempre principal (o sea, que **puede no ser principal**), "no tiene que ser siempre principal" es ambiguo: si "no tener que" indica falta de necesidad u obligación, entonces se parece a "no tiene por qué ser siempre principal", PERO si "no tener que" se interpreta como obligación negativa, entonces el significado es totalmente diferente, algo así como que existe una prohibición respecto de que sea siempre principal. Veamos cómo funciona en un contexto más concreto que la matemática:

- No tienes por qué vestirte siempre así (**no hay motivo** para que lo hagas).
- No tienes que vestirte siempre así (**puedes no** hacerlo).
- No tienes que vestirte siempre así (**no debes** hacerlo).